# Prettier in VS Code keeps breaking the line

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

So, I'm using VS Code with an extension called Prettier. The problem is that after I hit save my code is being "refined" but also separated into 2 lines even despite the fact it's a very short line and I still have plenty of space on the right. Could you please advice what setting is responsible for this conversion? It seems to me that I have checked all available options but unfortunately couldn't find anything which causes it.

[image]

Comment: Prettier is an *opinionated* formatter. You can read up on how to tweak that to some degree, but there are limits. Item #1 is what you are looking for: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

Answer (score 4):

`"prettier.printWidth": "80"`

in your `settings.json` or search for print width setting in the UI

Increase or decrease this setting. This limits the number of characters prettier limits a line to, it it exceeds this, it will try to break it into smaller ones.

Answer (score -2):

Search for settings.json in visual studio.
You will find a json file in this path `AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json` if it is a windows machine.

Add the below JSON in the file, If you keep `"editor.formatOnSave"` as `false` formatting won't happen when you save the file.
If you want to have this setting just make a specific property as `false` just the way I did for javascript and HTML in the below section.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "[handlebars]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[less]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
```

Comment: That won't fix the prettier problem. It will just turn off autoformatting which is bad idea.